# Using regular expressions

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to match emails from one of my own sites using a regular expression. Using `preg_match_all($pattern,$site,$array)` the results I get are duplicate. So for example, using:

```
$pattern = '/[\w-]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+/i';
```

I get:

```
Array
(
    [0] => uk@example1.com
    [1] => uk@example2.com
    [2] => sales@woot.com
    [3] => sales@woot.com
    [4] => info@regex.com
    [5] => info@regex.com
    [6] => direct@yadayada.com.au
    [7] => direct@yadayada.au
    [8] => adrian@blahblah.com
    [9] => adrian@blahblah.com
)
```

So, why am I getting duplicates?  Is this a problem with my regex?

The string I am searching is a URL using the file_get_contents() method.  I've checked the string to make sure it wasn't pulling the page twice.

Comment: What is the string you're searching?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if you are matching HTML you are probably matching both the href in the a tag and the content of the a tag.

```
<a href="mailto:uk@example1.com">uk@example1.com</a>
```

Comment: try using /mailto:([\w-]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+)/gi to get just the mailto  value

Answer (score 2):

If you're dealing with a small enough dataset, you could just throw the array into [array_unique()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) which will you give you back an array with the duplicates removed.

Comment: Of course it's probably better to understand what's going wrong but I figured I'd throw it out there :)